# devtools::test object not found

Tags: r, unit-testing, devtools

I have a series of unit tests that test against a large object (`y` in the MWE below). I have constructed `y` in `testthat.R`, and tests pass if I run `R CMD check`, but not if I run `devtools::test()`.

How can I ensure `devtools::test()` runs the test in the correct environment? Or what is the canonical way to make an object available to all tests?

https://github.com/HughParsonage/testGlobalEnv

**./tests/testthat.R**

```
library(testthat)
library(testGlobalEnv)

y <- 1:5

test_check("testGlobalEnv")
```

**./R/adder.R**

```
#' Adds numbers
#' @param x A vector of numbers
#' @export

adder <- function(x){
  sum(x)
}
```

**./tests/test_adder.R**

```
test_that("adder", {
  expect_equal(adder(y), 15)
})
```

`R CMD check` shows the tests passing; however, running `devtools::test()`:

```
1
Failed -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Error: adder (@test_adder.R#2) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
object 'y' not found
1: expect_equal(adder(y), 15) at C:\Users\Hugh Parsonage\Documents\Github\testGlobalEnv/tests/testthat/test_adder.R:2
2: compare(object, expected, ...)
3: adder(y)
```

Comment: It's the name of the package that is being tested.

Comment: `install_github('HughParsonage/testGlobalEnv')`

Comment: does `y <- 1:5` need to exist inside `test_adder.R` (or even inside `test_that("adder", {})` ?

Comment: That prevents the error, but I'd like to avoid adding it to every test (as it's not necessary for the CMD check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the question "what is the canonical way to make an object available to all tests": Just put your shared data, computations, ... in `/test/testthat/helper-mytitle.R` and it will be available for all tests.